# Why is check_password_hash always returning False?

Tags: python, hash

The check_password_hash function always returns false.

I generate the hash like this

```
hashed_password = generate_password_hash('password',method='pbkdf2:sha1:2000', salt_length=15)
```

then saved in a database,

```
db.execute(
            "INSERT INTO users (username, hash, Fullname, email) VALUES(?, ?,?,?)", username, hashed_password, Fullname, mail)
```

but I can't get it to validate using

```
       # Query database for username
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?",
                          request.form.get("username"))

        # Ensure username exists and password is correct
        if len(rows) != 1:
            return apology("invalid username and/or password -0", 403)

        if not check_password(rows[0]["hash"], request.form.get("password")):
```

I don't know what's wrong.

I did try creating this but same result

```
# check for password
def check_password(hash, password):
    return check_password_hash(hash, password)
```

Comment: What kind of `hash` value are you getting out of the database?

Comment: It's also perplexing why you have a function to call a function with exactly the same arguments. It's not necessary.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show us the code in `check_password_hash()`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, and keep in mind I may be completely wrong, it seems to me that you are comparing a hashed password with what seems to be the raw user input.

My assumption is that in this line:

```
if not check_password(rows[0]["hash"], request.form.get("password")):
```

`request.form.get("password")` refers to the framework you are using and that's probably an unhashed password?

So (as others mentioned in the comments) it depends on what `check_password_hash()` does.

---

on another note, my experience with hashes is that they are often returned as `bytes() / b''`, which means you could be comparing 2 things that look the same, but technically are not.

---

UPDATE:

After a bit more digging it seems like you are using `werkzeug.security`, which clarifies a lot the functions in question. So I would proceed by adding a `print()`, for each value, right before you compare them. This way we can determine if there's something wrong with the data and approximately where it occurs.

Comment: The truth that After several hours, looking for solutions and reading manuals and documentation, I found a simple error in my code.

this is the correct code.

        # Hash the user password
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(
            password, method='pbkdf2:sha256', salt_length=15)

I had this.

hashed_password = generate_password_hash('password',method='pbkdf2:sha1:2000', salt_length=15)


password in quotes, it would never work because the password generated was the word in quotes and not the one that the user put.

Comment: It didn't even occur to me! I noticed the changed method to `'pbkdf2:sha1:2000'` but from the documentation it seemed valid (although probably not ideal). I'm glad you found it. Cheers!